# Not REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a large table with phone numbers.  The phone numbers are all strings and supposed to be '+9628789878' or similar. (a "+" sign followed by between 9 and 13 digits.)

A user bug uncovered one row with the string '+987+9873678298'.  Clearly it shouldn't be there and I'd like to find out how many other cases there are of this or other such errors.

I tried this query but it's not doing the job. My thinking is anything that's not like this string.  (Oh, the table is not indexed by phone_number.)

```
SELECT user_key,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       phone_number
FROM   users u
WHERE  regexp_like(phone_number, '[^\+[0-9]*]')
AND    phone_number IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `phone_number IS NOT NULL` is unnecessary because NULL values won't make it through `regexp_like` anyway.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you need to find all the rows where `phone_number` is not made by exactly a `'+'` followed by 9-13 digits, this should do the work:

```
select *
from users 
where not regexp_like(phone_number, '^\+[0-9]{9,13}$')
```

What it does:

- `^` the beginning of the string, to avoid things like `'XX +123456789'`
- `\+` the '+'
- `[0-9]{9,13}` a sequence of 9-13 digits
- `$` the end of the string, to avoid strings like `'+123456789 XX'`

Another way, with no regexp, could be the following:

```
where not (
                /* strings of 10-14 chars */
                length(phone_number) between 10 and 14 
                /* ... whose first is a + */
            and substr(phone_number, 1, 1 ) = '+' 
                /* ...and that become a '+' after removing all the digits */
            and nvl(translate(phone_number, 'X0123456789', 'X'), '+') = '+' 
          )
```

This could be faster than the regexp approach, even if it's based on more conditions, but I believe only a test will tell you which one is the best performing.